# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/u161146050/public_html/application/views/test1.php on line 49

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, xampp

I have a problem about this thing...I have been doing this in XAMPP and nothing goes wrong..but whenever I upload it to the hosting it always display this.

> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/u161146050/public_html/application/views/test1.php on line 49.

I don't know why it appears in `line 49`, but during I was doing it in `localhost` it doesn't appear.

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td class="warning" id="bold">Book Id</td>
        <td class="danger" id="bold">Book Title</td>
        <td class="warning" id="bold">Author</td>
        <td class="danger" id="bold">Status</td>
        <td class="warning" id="bold">Borrower</td>
        <td class="danger" id="bold">options</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    include('inc/config.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books";
    $result = $link->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="warning"><?php echo $row['bookNumber']?></td>
        <td class="danger"><?php echo $row['title']?></td>
        <td class="warning"><?php echo $row['author']?></td>
        <td class="danger"><?php echo $row['status']?></td>
        <td class="warning"><?php echo $row['borrower']?></td>
        <td class="danger"><form  method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"><div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
<?php    }
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Dude, debug your result like **print_r($result)**

Comment: show your include('inc/config.php') file

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);{
```

Comment: Please explain your answer